# Automatical creation of DB schema based on data classes

Tags: c#, sql-server, automation, database-schema

I've got a bunch of classes describing a data structure. Now I'll have to write SQL code to mirror said structure int the DB. It'd be nice to have that generated for me automatically. After some Googling I got to a few suggestions but most were outdated and none of them were for Azure.

1. Is it possible to "inject" DB schema based on class structure into Azure DB?
2. Is is possible to simultaneously do the same to a local DB for testing?

If so, I'd like to see some suggestions, link or at least keywords to Google. Apparently, I must admit that I've failed with a good search and need help with that. (Head hanging painfully low burdened with shame.)

(I've been instructed not to use code-first strategy due to a combination of performance issues and general suspicioness from the client.)

Comment: You've been instructed not to use code-first, but everything you have described is ***exactly*** code-first... Can you clarify? However, worst case, writing a reflection-based tsql table-generator is only a couple of hours work (based on having done it many times)

Comment: @MarcGravell My clarification would involve describing the client in terms that, would she be to learn what I wrote, the contract'd be most likely terminated. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I'll give it one more try to sell the code-first to her. Is it applicable directly to a set of classes describing the model or do I need to extend it somehow, set up stuff etc.?

Comment: Just removed "Azure" tag, as the question is purely SQL Server related. And it's solution, whatever it is, has no specifics to Windows Azure SQL Database. In any case, whatever approach you take (and it will be madness to not go for Code-First!), do not *ever* forget to include *retry logic* in everything you do with your Database when it is in the cloud (ref. http://geekswithblogs.net/ScottKlein/archive/2012/01/27/understanding-sql-azure-throttling-and-implementing-retry-logic.aspx)